# Has anyone experienced sIFR (436) vanishing in IE7, then returning if you resize the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, sifr

Has anyone experienced sIFR (436) vanishing in IE7, then returning if you resize the browser?

It's only been happening with sIFR 436.

Thanks,
Wilson

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using position absolute, rather than relative.  Relative seems to be the better positioning here, but anyhow, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution: you need to specifically set a 'height' property in your css file that contains the elements sifr will be operating on. for example, say you are converting h2 and h3 tags to sifr, you need to make sure they have something like h3 { height:20px; } in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works with position:absolute; as well as with width:100%;